# how to select specific column header and create view using the command

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a create table tab1

```
CREATE TABLE tab1(
 tabid number(10),
 tabname  varchar2(10),
 tabtype  varchar2(10),
 tabstatus varchar2(10),
 tabaddress varchar2(10)
);
```

I have tired to select column header using the following code:

```
SELECT *
FROM myschema.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tab1';
```

I want to create a view using columns headers.

Comment: do you mean columns when you say column headers ?

Comment: no , i mean columns header only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can find information about column in the `user_tab_cols` view.
You can retrieve the column headers with a query like:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM USER_TAB_COLS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TAB1'
```

If you are not connected as the table owner you can use this (make sure schema and table name are in capital letters):

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM ALL_TAB_COLS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TAB1' 
                                           AND OWNER = 'MYSCHEMA'
```